# I have my background changing colour. How can I now also change my text’s colour?

Tags: javascript

I am brand new here, and this is my first question.

I have the background of my website changing colour in a sequence each time the browser refreshes, which is great (yay).

Now I want to also change the font colour property associated with my body, so I can have a different page theme for every refresh.

For example, on refresh:

Red background with blue text, then Orange background with green text, etc.

Any idea how to add this to my existing code elegantly?

I tried to duplicate my code and target the color attribute, instead of background-color, just to see if it would work, and it did not.

Thank you for any help!!!

```js
function loadNextImage1() {

  //declare image directory path and image array
  var colors = ["#red", "#blue", "#green"];
  colors[0] = "#red";
  colors[1] = "#blue";
  colors[2] = "#green";

  //get current cookie value
  var currentIndex = parseInt(getCookie());
  var background = colors[currentIndex];

  document.body.style.backgroundColor = background;

  //set next cookie index
  currentIndex += 1;
  currentIndex %= colors.length;
  setCookie(currentIndex);
}

function setCookie(someint) {
  var now = new Date();
  var addDays = now.getDate() + 7
  now.setDate(addDays); // cookie expires in 7 days
  var theString = 'imgID=' + escape(someint) + ';expires=' + now.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = theString;
}

function getCookie() {
  var output = "0";
  if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    var temp = unescape(document.cookie);
    temp = temp.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
      if (temp[i].indexOf('imgID') != -1) {
        temp = temp[i].split('=');
        output = temp.pop();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

```html
<body onload="loadNextImage1();">
  <img id="ImageRefresh"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Unless you prevent a traditional page refresh with the event preventdefault method, you should keep some sort of state in the user's browser in order to _know_ when they have changed or reloaded the page. A common way to do that is using localStorage and saving/comparing on every page load the current image with the array of images

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 sets which add up to your combination

JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vuo5pmdt/

```
function loadNextImage1() {
  //declare image directory path and image array
  var backgrounds = ["red", "blue", "green"];
  var foregrounds = ["white", "yellow", "black"];

  //get current cookie value
  var colorIndex = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('colorIndex') || '{"foreground":0, "background":0}');

  document.body.style.backgroundColor = backgrounds[colorIndex.background];
  document.body.style.color = foregrounds[colorIndex.foreground];

  //set next cookie index
  var next = {
    foreground: (colorIndex.foreground + 1) % foregrounds.length,
    background: (colorIndex.background + 1) % backgrounds.length
  };
  localStorage.setItem('colorIndex', JSON.stringify(next))
}
```

Comment: Wow, this looks exactly like what I was trying to do. Thank you!